# Copy values from one table to another based on column comparison

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, copy

I have a Question and Answer table in SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Question:**

```
q_id
question_text
```

**Answer:**

```
a_id
question_text
answer_text
```

This is obviously bad design. The question_text field is duplicated in the `Question` and `Answer` tables and there is no foreign key relationship between `Answer` and `Question`. I want to create this relation by finding the `Question` (the `q_id`) for each `Answer` that is already present in the `Answer` table. I would do this by matching the `question_text` value that is copied to the `Answer` table to the rows in the `Question` table.

This is what I'd like to do in pseudo code.

- create a nullable `q_id` field in the `Answer` table (nullable because there is already data in the `Answer` table)
- select everything from the `Answer` table.
- for each row in the result
  -- select the corresponding question from the `Question` table by comparing the `question_text` value.
  -- insert the `q_id` into the nullable `q_id` column in the `Answer` table
- change the `q_id` column in the `Answer` to not nullable.

Could you help me achieve this in SQL Server 2008 R2? Thanks.

PS: All `question_text` values in the `Question` table are unique.

Comment: Hmm, why don't use just create another table? `create table newanswer as select blabla`, and then rename answer to answer.old and newanswer to answer?

Comment: Hi fge, there is already data in the Answer table, so I need to hook up the existing Answers to their Question somehow. The only way I can do this is by looking at the question_text value, because that has been copied to the Answer table.

Comment: Well, my solution wouldn't lose data in the answer table! OK, look at the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to:

```
select a.a_id, q.q_id, a.answer_text
    into NewAnswer
    from Answer a, Question q
    where a.question_text = q.question_text;
```

Once done, add constraints on `NewAnswer`, rename `Answer` to something else and `NewAnswer` to `Answer`.

[edit: fix syntax, according to [this link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic468306-145-1.aspx)]

Comment: I think this should be a good solution. However SQL Server is complaining about a syntax error near 'as'. It's expecting a '('. I put everything after 'as' between braces, but no luck. It keeps complaining.

Comment: See post edit. In fact, "create table as select" is Oracle only.

Answer (score 3):

First step - create the new `q_id` column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Answer ADD q_id INT NULL
```

Second step - update based on `question_text`

```
UPDATE dbo.Answer
SET q_id = q.q_id
FROM dbo.Question q
WHERE dbo.Answer.question_text = q.question_text
```

Third step - if you don't have any NULL values:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Answer ALTER COLUMN q_id INT NOT NULL
```

Fourth step - **establish the FK link!**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Answer 
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Answer_Question
  FOREIGN KEY(q_id) REFERENCES dbo.Question(q_id)
```

Fifth step - drop the old `question_text` column

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Answer
  DROP COLUMN question_text
```

And of course - as always:

- try this on a **test setup first**
- before you do this on your production, **make sure** to have **at least one** very recent data backup at hand

Comment: Hello marc. Your answer looks good as well. However, after the addition of the new q_id field in the beginning, SQL Server doesn't recognize the new field. I don't know why that happens. In the second UPDATE query the q_id field is underlined in red, while it is in the table. Strange.,

Comment: @Julius: you need to run these steps each on its own (with a `GO` in between them) - you cannot run all of them together. That's just the way SQL Server works.....